# How i can set tws jobmanager traces?

Tags: tivoli-work-scheduler

I have some issues on my tws dynamic agent , how i can set the traces to understand better the problems  ?

the agent is not enable to connect to the server

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit the file:
`<TWA_home>/TWS/ITA/cpa/config/JobManager.ini`
and change the value of **JobManager.loggerfl.level** from 3000 (the default) to 1000.

Example:

```
JobManager.loggerfl.level = 1000
```

Then, you have to restart the dynamic agent.
This change will make the agent write more information in the files:

- $TWA_HOME/TWS/stdlist/JM/JobManager_message.log
- $TWA_HOME/TWS/stdlist/JM/JobManager_trace.log

Have a look to these pages for more information:

- https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSGSPN_9.2.0/com.ibm.tivoli.itws.doc_9.2/distr/src_tr/awstrdynagtlogfiles.htm
- https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSGSPN_9.2.0/com.ibm.tivoli.itws.doc_9.2/distr/src_ad/awsadconflogmesprops.htm

Answer (score 0):

I also suggest to increase the size of the trace files and the number of trace files. These are the entries in JobManager.ini

```
JobManager.trfl.level = 1000
JobManager.trhd.maxFileBytes = 5024000
JobManager.trhd.maxFiles = 10
```

These settings set the trace level to the DEBUG level (1000), 10 trace files are written, each trace file has the size of 5 Mb.